# How to parse the elements of a list as arguments for a method? Specifically, for Google Ads API

Tags: python, parsing, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to modularize a type of report from the API. This is my query for the request:

```
content = ['CampaignId', 'AdvertisingChannelType', ...]
report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                       .Select(content)
                       .From('CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                       .During(start_date=since,end_date=until)
                       .Build())
```

However, I'm having a problem with the `.Select()` statement since its common usage is `.Select('CampaignId', 'AdvertisingChannelType', ...)` (as the list but without the brackets `[]`) and in my query I'm parsing the arguments as a list, which of course returns an error.

My question is, how can I parse the elements of `content` as required? I've tried turning the list into a string but it doesn't work as all the list becomes a single element. I can't assign by hand the elements since it's number may vary (will be used for more than one client).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try `.Select(*content)`

Comment: @Vova This worked, Could you provide me some information to understand the usage of the star there? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly if this is helpful, but maybe try looking [into python maps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/).

Comment: Tried but didn't work, thank you anyway. The answer of @vova did it.